# Is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right )$ open?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

This [.pdf](http://www.math.umaine.edu/~farlow/sec53.pdf) on Example 2 (page 4 on paper), it says that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right )=\{0\}\cup (-1/2,1/2)\cup\dots=(-1,1)$$
is open. Please check Theorem 1 on page 3. How can this Example be open, if $\{0\}$ is closed?

Comment: Why do you think $\{0\}$ being closed would imply the union is not open?

Comment: Furthermore, $\{0\}$ is not in the union on the left of the equality. The first term is $(0, 0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < x < 0\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Because I thought that every onepoint set in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Theorem 1 says "The  union  of  any  collection (possibly infinite) of open sets is open... ". If $\{ 0\}$ were open, I would accept that the Example is open.

Comment: Singletons are closed. If the union was $\{0\}\cup (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})\cup\dots$, which it isn't, then instead of using Theorem 1, the openness would be established by determining the union, in this case $(-1, 1)$, and seeing that it is open.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks. I think I understand now.

Comment: A union of any collection of open sets (including the case of infinitely many of them) is always open.  The set $\{0\}$ is not open, however (1) it is a subset of the other sets, so you still have a union of open sets; and (2) $\{0\}$ shouldn't be there anyway.  The interval $[0,0]$ is the set $\{0\}$, but the interval $(0,0)$ is empty, not $\{0\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I realized the mistake. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Note that your sets are increasing.. $\left(-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \subseteq \left(-1+\frac{1}{n+1},1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ and as you let $n$ tend to infinity, $-1+\frac{1}{n}$ will tend to $-1$ - but never actually reach it - and similarly for $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Thus you end up with $(-1,1)$. Also note that $\{0\}\cup (-2,3) = (-2,3)$ which is open even though $\{0\}$ is a closed set. Unioning open and closed sets doesn't follow any general rule (you can only say meaningful things on a case-by-case basis).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two points here:

1. $[0,1]\cup(-2,2)=(-2,2)$ is an open interval, which is open. The union of a closed set and an open set *can* be open, or closed, or neither (or both!).
2. For $n=1$, you have $(0,0)=\varnothing$, and not $\{0\}$.

In any case, $(-1,1)$ is an open interval, the fact you could write it as the union of some sets which may or may not be open is meaningless to the fact that the interval is open.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)$ is open for any $n$,
$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right )$ is open because union of open sets is always open (Theorem 1).

Clearly
$$
\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)\subset (-1,1)
$$
On the other hand, for any $x\in(-1,1)$, there is a $N$ such that $x<1/N$. So 
$$
(-1,1)\subset\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
This means
$$
\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)= (-1,1)
$$
Also since $0\in \left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)$ for any $n$ 
$$  0\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right)=(-1,1)$$
 And thus 
$$\{0\}\cup (-1,1)=(-1,1)$$